# how to append the value property as key in javascript in order to avoid hard coding keys?

Tags: javascript

how to append the value property as key in javascript ?

```
const updateValue = (arrayOfObj, dataObj) => {
dataObj.item[0].issue_date = dataObj.dates.issueDate;
dataObj.item[0].delivered_date = dataObj.dates.deliveredDate;
return dataObj
};
```

Instead of hard coding key issue_date & delivered_date. i wanted to use arrayOfObj to map those two key using filter method.

```
arrayOfObj = [{itemId: "1234", label: "XYZ", address: "GGYGYFTDF", phoneNo: "1234555"}, {lookupIssueDateKey: "issue_date", lookupDeliveredDateKey: "delivered_date", lookupPackageDate: "package_date"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access it just by

```
const key = arrayOfObj[1].lookupIssueDateKey
dataObj.item[0][key]
```